# Can formal languages have verbs?

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-language, language, natural-language

Perhaps stupid question but I ask nonetheless.

**The question:** Can Formal languages have a concept of a verb? If never, why can't they?

**Context**: In natural language, we have verbs to describe action. In Formal language (eg: Natural deduction), I only see statements. I have never seen something concepts like "subject" , "verb" or "object" in N.D. However, clearly Formal Language still has a Grammar. There is still a syntax  to say what makes sense and what doesn't.

This leads me to the impression that requirement to go from Natural to Formal is to give up verbs.

---

Related questions:

[Explaining Formal language trough a Natural one](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/91633/how-is-it-possible-to-explain-a-logical-language-through-a-natural-one?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C20.0266)

[Is Art beyond logic?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/92306/is-art-beyond-logic?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C8.4739)

Comment: There's nothing fundamentally non-formal about verbs. Look at [dynamic logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-dynamic/#SynSem) or [TLA](https://lamport.azurewebsites.net/pubs/lamport-actions.pdf), for example.

Comment: "is" is a verb. https://writingexplained.org/is-is-a-verb

Comment: Is there much difference between verbs and the usual predicates in formal languages?...

Comment: Some have theorized that in programming (a kind of formal language), functions can be seen as verbs (and variables as nouns).

Comment: in line with @NoahSchweber's comment, consider a simple imperative language, with commands such as "skip", "loop", "assign". more generally, it depends on what you mean by verb. In any case tho, verbs or lack thereof aren't the best characterization for the distinction between formal and natural languages

Comment: @TrystwithFreedom The only fundamental difference is that natural languages are natural, in the sense that no one designed them, they just arise out of the interactions between people, while formal languages are invariably created and developed purposefully. To answer your question, formal languages are created for some specific purpose so that whether there are verbs only depends on the needs of the creators of the language. Programming languages are perhaps the epitome of formal languages and they have verbs, verbs which express the *actions* the programmer wants the computer *to perform*.

Comment: Yes. The goal of all languages (formal or informal) is to communicate. How would you replace the verb "to be" in "_a triangle IS a polygon_"? The equal sign is essentially a verb "to be", in `pi=3.1416` (which reads "_pi is three..._"). How would you skip it?